# jQuery Datepicker Highlight my given date & remove current date highlighted

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I tried `setDate` function, it added `ui-state-active` for date mentioned which is fine.

I have written class for `ui-state-active` make that hightlight display.

But the current date is also showing as highlighted with `ui-state-hightlight`.
I want to remove this class adding for current date.

I am guessing this highlighting is happening through default attribute of date picker function.

But it is not having, written like this:

```
$(".datepickerfuture").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "../images/blank.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 3):

By overriding the default css **`.ui-datepicker-today`** and **`a.ui-state-highlight`** of with the below one.

```
.ui-datepicker-today a.ui-state-highlight {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    background: #e6e6e6 url(/themeroller/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #555555;    
}
```

Check out this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nYzpy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by very simple way: I've just removed all css rules of ui-state-highlight class from jquery.ui.css. Current date are higlighting with black border (similar as date picking in Windows 7) by adding only one css rule to ui-state-highlight class:

```
.ui-state-highlight {
    border-color: black !important;
}
```

But I used only one date picker ui widget in my project.